# In $k$-means, how is it NP-hard if the dimensionality of the data is at least $2$ ($d\geq 2$)?

Tags: clustering, dimensionality-reduction, k-means, algorithms, fuzzy-c-means-clustering

In $k$-means, how is it NP-hard if the dimensionality of the data is at least $2$ ($d\geq 2$)? Can someone justify or give reasons to this statement?

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397510003269#:~:text=Drineas%20et%20al.%20%5B9%5D%2C%20Aloise%20et%20al.%20%5B2%5D%2C,number%20of%20clusters%2C%20is%20part%20of%20the%20input.  might answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that it's not terribly surprising that the problem is NP-hard: there are **a lot** of possible clusterings; the usual algorithm doesn't claim to find the optimum solution; the usual algorithm is purely local and so might well miss a global optimum in some weird data setup.

To be NP-hard, the problem only has to be hard in some non-negligible fraction of datasets; in particular, it might still be easy for any data set that genuinely has $k$ clusters but hard for some data sets that don't really have $k$ clusters. Also, $k$ is part of the input, so we're allowing $k$ to grow with $n$; the fixed-$k$ problem isn't NP-hard.

The [paper linked in @jbowman's comment](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397510003269#:%7E:text=Drineas%20et%20al.%20%5B9%5D%2C%20Aloise%20et%20al.%20%5B2%5D%2C,number%20of%20clusters%2C%20is%20part%20of%20the%20input) shows how to construct planar point layouts where lots of the interpoint differences are equal and the number of clusters is roughly $n/2$. The question of which points optimally go in the same cluster then becomes a global rather than a local problem and local algorithms aren't going to work well.  For the precise details of how this gets reduced to the known-hard problem 'planar 3SAT' you'll need to read the paper. From a data analysis point of view it's not really a problem, since it's not a setting where you'd be using $k$-means, but it does illustrate why it might be hard to prove useful results about $k$-means even in settings where it's useful.

One of the links from the paper is to [this](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ecswamy/papers/kmeansfnl.pdf), which looks at how to modify the usual algorithm so it has probabilistic guarantees of getting close to the optimal clustering in polynomial time even for large $k$, assuming there really is a good $k$-cluster solution.